# Ban And unban only working if have no role pls

Tags: python, discord

So my discord bot is working and stuff but i can only kick/ban if they don't have a role.
I really don't wanna be removing the role before kicking or banning someone.

```
my code
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member} was banned!")

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member} was kicked!")

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    bannedUsers = await ctx.guild.bans()
    name, discriminator = member.split("#")

    for ban in bannedUsers:
        user = ban.user

        if(user.name, user.discriminator) == (name, discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} was unbanned.")
            return
```

Comment: What is the traceback if they have a role? Please include that.

Comment: Probably a role hierarchy issue. Make sure your bot has a higher role than the ones you are trying to ban.

Comment: Thank you Ceres, I did need it to be higher than people I'm kicking

Answer (score 0):

Since the solution was only in the comments here is the solution to the problem based on **Ceres**'s comment:

The bot's role should ideally always be above all other roles. This guarantees a smooth flow.
This way the bot is able to take over actions for all roles as well.
Your mistake will have been the following:

```py
Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Say: The bot didn't have enough permissions because it was under the actual role the user had. Result: The user could not be kicked.

*You may also have a look at the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/opcodes-and-status-codes).*

Comment: Thank you, but yea it started to work with no errors.

Comment: I just explained it if other platform user face the same problem.